# Azure API retrieving SAS policy, error InvalidHostName

Tags: azure, rest, api, access-token, bearer-token

I am trying to create an Event Hub in Azure using the REST APi ( with Postman ) but I am getting an error in the process of generating the SAS token.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/0e3603bd-2f0b-43e2-b9b5-5d456791cf33/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=myclientid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=myclientsecret' \
--data-urlencode 'resource=https://management.azure.com/'
```

I store the bearer token and use it to authentificate on the following requeste:
First create the Event Hub namespace :

'''
curl --location --request PUT 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/6fa11037-363b-4ff4-a5a2-f4e93efa527c/resourceGroups/easypeasybi/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/easypeasybi?api-version=2017-04-01' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer mybearertoken' \
--data-raw '{"location":"francecentral"}'

'''
Now in order to create the Event Hub, I need to build a SAS token,therefore I need to retrieve the SAS policy first:
The creation of the Namespace generate a SAS policy named RootManageSharedAccessKey, I can list all the policy using this call :

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/6fa11037-363b-4ff4-a5a2-f4e93efa527c/resourceGroups/easypeasybi/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/easypeasybi/AuthorizationRules?api-version=2017-04-01' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer mybearertoken'
```

Lastly, I am trying to retrieve the RootManageSharedAccessKey policy but I am getting an error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidHostName",
        "message": "The provided host name 'easypeasybi.servicebus.windows.net' is not whitelisted. "
    }
}
```

The code I am using is the following

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/6fa11037-363b-4ff4-a5a2-f4e93efa527c/resourceGroups/easypeasybi/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/easypeasybi/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey/listKeys?api-version=2017-04-01' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8' \
--header 'Host: easypeasybi.servicebus.windows.net' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer mybearertoken' \
--data-raw '<entry xmlns='\''http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'\''>  
  <content type='\''application/xml'\''>  
    <EventHubDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">  
    </EventHubDescription>  
  </content>  
</entry>  '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header, the `Host` should be `management.azure.com`.

So in you command, change this line of code

`--header 'Host: easypeasybi.servicebus.windows.net' \`

to

```
--header 'Host: management.azure.com' \
```

Comment: Sorry, i confuse mark as a solution and mark it as useful.Done